# Python: Find all nodes connected to n (tuple)

Tags: python, algorithm, search, graph, path

I want to find out whether I can reach all nodes from a certain node. I am not interested in the path, I just want to output YES or NO if I can or cannot. Let's assume I have the following graph - As a constraint, I need to represent my nodes as a tuple (i,j):

```
graph={
    (1,1): [(1,2),(2,2)]
    (1,2): [(1,3)]
    (1,3): [(1,2),(2,3)]
    (2,2): [(3,3)]
    (2,3): []
    (3,3): [(2,2)]
}
```

Now, I need to show if I can reach from (1,1), (2,2) or (3,3), i.e. (i,j) with i = j, all other nodes where i != j. If yes, print(YES) - if no, print(NO).
The example mentioned above would output YES for node(1,1), since I can reach (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3) via node (1,1).

I tried to use the following

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(graph)
for reachable_node in nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(G, source=None):
    print reachable_node
```

However, if I declare (1,1), (2,2) or (3,3) as my source in nx.dfs_postorder.nodes(), I get, e.g., following error -> KeyError: (1,1)

Which function or library (the more standard the library is the better!!) should I use to indicate whether I can reach all nodes from any of the (i, i) nodes?

Thanks for all clarifications! I am a new member, so if my question doesn't follow the Stackoverflow guidelines, feel free to tell me how I can improve my next questions!

Comment: Just wanted to know what do the values `i, j` mean in the tuple for the node `(i, j)` ?

Comment: @svasa - (i, j) are all the possible variations in which i and j can be represented in a tuple. For example, if we have 4 nodes (n = 4), our graph would represent all combinations of i = 1, ..., 4 and j = 1, ..., 4.
(2, 3) = (3, 2) in this case

Comment: I attempted this without `nx.dfs_postorder.nodes()`, using `shortest_path` instead. is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question. You could try an exhaustive approach with a `try/except` block using `nx.shortest_path` like this:

```
import networkx as nx

graph={
    (1,1): [(1,2),(2,2)],
    (1,2): [(1,3)],
    (1,3): [(1,2),(2,3)],
    (2,2): [(3,3)],
    (3,3): [(2,2)],
    (4,4): [(1,3)],
    (5,5): []
}

G = nx.Graph(graph)
nodes = G.nodes()
balanced_nodes = [node for node in G.nodes() if node[0] == node[1]]
unbalanced_nodes = [node for node in G.nodes() if node[0] != node[1]]
for balanced_node in balanced_nodes:
    for unbalanced_node in unbalanced_nodes:
        connected = True
        try:
            path = nx.shortest_path(G,balanced_node, unbalanced_node)
        except:
            connected = False
            break
    print(balanced_node, ": ", connected)
```

This results in:

```
(1, 1) :  True
(2, 2) :  True
(3, 3) :  True
(4, 4) :  True
(5, 5) :  False
```

Answer (score 3):

This program should do the work and it uses just standard library (basically gives you all possible states that can be visited for a given starting point):

```
graph={
    (1,1): [(1,2), (2,2)],
    (1,2): [(1,3)],
    (1,3): [(1,2), (2,3)],
    (2,2): [(3,3)],
    (2,3): [],
    (3,3): [(2,2)]
}

node0 = (1,1) #choose the starting node
node0_connections = [node0] #this list will contain all the possible states that can be visited from node0
for node in node0_connections: 
     for node_to in graph[node]:
         if  node0_connections.count(node_to) == 0:
             node0_connections.append(node_to)                
print 'All possible states to be visted from node', node0,':', node0_connections,'.'
count = node0_connections.count((1,2)) + node0_connections.count((1,3)) + node0_connections.count((2,2))
if count == 3:
    print 'YES'
else:
    print 'NO'
```